# ITfoxtec SAML 2.0 Session TimeOut

Tags: saml, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Am using SAML2.0 AUTH with help of ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Mvc package   but I need to increase the session timeout to a 2 to 3 days . But currently default value there . How We can override the session time out . With .net core 3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom session timeout in the `AssertionConsumerService` method in the Auth Controller. Se [documentation](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2).

Set session timeout to 2 days:

```
await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, 
  lifetime: new TimeSpan(2, 0,0,0), 
  claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));
```

It is also possible to configure the session as persistence:

```
await saml2AuthnResponse.CreateSession(HttpContext, 
  lifetime: new TimeSpan(2, 0,0,0), isPersistent: true, 
  claimsTransform: (claimsPrincipal) => ClaimsTransform.Transform(claimsPrincipal));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .I will change the code and let u know.

Comment: I'm wondering if you had any lock. Please rate the answer if it was helpful.